# Create a new Contact in Telegram with C#

Tags: c#, telegram

I Have a problem in using Telegram APIs in C#.
I want to create a contact in telegram with a specific phone number so i can send messages directly to a phone number that was not in my contacts.

How can i create a contact with specific phone number in telegram with c#?

I tried to use TLSharp to do this but i did not found any method.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing for it in Telegram Bot API: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

Comment: so its not possible to send a message directly to a phone number?

Comment: You can't send a message to user if user haven't contacted bot first.

Answer (score 1):

There is now [WTelegramClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WTelegramClient/) library, using the latest Telegram Client API protocol (connecting as a user, not bot).

The library is very complete but also very simple to use. Follow the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient#readme) for an easy introduction.

To create a contact by phone number and send a message to it, the whole Program.cs would be as simple as:

```cs
using TL;

using var client = new WTelegram.Client(); // or Client(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable)
await client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
var contact = await client.Contacts_ImportContacts(new[] { new InputPhoneContact { phone = "+PHONENUMBER" } });
await client.SendMessageAsync(contact.users[0], "Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

TLSharp now has method ImportContactsAsync, you can use it like this:

```
var list = new List<TLInputPhoneContact> 
            {
                new TLInputPhoneContact() { Phone = phoneNumberTo, FirstName = defaultName, LastName = defaultLastname, ClientId = 0}
            };

            await client.ImportContactsAsync(list);
```

Wasted some hours trying to find how to do it in the internet, but hadn't found, hope it will help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Program
    {
        static string Config(string what)
        {
            switch (what)
            {
                case "api_id": return "...";
                case "api_hash": return "...";
                case "phone_number": return "...";
                case "verification_code": Console.Write("Code: "); return Console.ReadLine();
                case "first_name": return "John";      // if sign-up is required
                case "last_name": return "Doe";        // if sign-up is required
                case "password": return "...";     // if user has enabled 2FA
                default: return null;                  // let WTelegramClient decide the default config
            }
        }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello This is test app!");
            using var client = new WTelegram.Client(Config); // or Client(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable)
            await client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var contact = await client.Contacts_ImportContacts(new[] { new InputPhoneContact { phone = "+...", first_name = "Iran", last_name = "Tester" } });
                    object p = await client.SendMessageAsync(contact.users[contact.users.Keys.First()], "Hello");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Right Code that works actually

Comment: Library Name Is: WTelegramClient

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).